# How to set standard role in all buttons

Tags: css

i have input textbox css  and I found way to make it a global to change all textbox design without assign "cssclass" property of each textbox in this code :

```
input[type=text]
{
  background-color:black;
  font-family:Callibri;
  color:white;
}
```

Now I want the same thing for all buttons , how can i make it ??

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `input[type=button]`. If you want the same styling for both inputs then all you have to do is:

```
input[type=text], 
input[type=button]
{
  background-color:black;
  font-family:Callibri;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="button"]
{
  background-color:black;
  font-family:Callibri;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not working , i was try :

```
input[type=button] {
  position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #f1f1f1;
color: black;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 16px 30px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center; }
```

also not work.